# Open Dialog after clicking on Button

Tags: java, android, button, dialog

I have implemented a WhatsNew Dialog to my Android app. But it only shows when a user installed and open a new version for the first time.

I want to create a button that when its clicked opens the same WhatsNew Dialog again. How can I do so? I already created the button, here is the code of the WhatNewScreen Activity:

```
public class WhatsNewScreen {
    private static final String LOG_TAG                 = "WhatsNewScreen";

    private static final String LAST_VERSION_CODE_KEY   = "last_version_code";

    private Activity            mActivity;

    // Constructor memorize the calling Activity ("context")
    public WhatsNewScreen(Activity context) {
        mActivity = context;
    }

    // Show the dialog only if not already shown for this version of the application
    public void show() {
        try {
            // Get the versionCode of the Package, which must be different (incremented) in each release on the market in the AndroidManifest.xml
            final PackageInfo packageInfo = mActivity.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(mActivity.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);

            final SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mActivity);
            final long lastVersionCode = prefs.getLong(LAST_VERSION_CODE_KEY, 0);

            if (packageInfo.versionCode != lastVersionCode) {
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "versionCode " + packageInfo.versionCode + "is different from the last known version " + lastVersionCode);

                final String title = mActivity.getString(R.string.app_name) + " v" + packageInfo.versionName;

                final String message = mActivity.getString(R.string.whatsnew);

                // Show the News since last version
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mActivity)
                        .setTitle(title)
                        .setMessage(message)
                        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new Dialog.OnClickListener() {

                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                // Mark this version as read
                                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                                editor.putLong(LAST_VERSION_CODE_KEY, packageInfo.versionCode);
                                editor.commit();
                                dialogInterface.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                builder.create().show();
            } else {
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "versionCode " + packageInfo.versionCode + "is already known");
            }

        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

I tried it with this in my MainAcitivty to open the Dialog. Please take a look on the Picture:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nav1.png

But when I open the App and click the button it force closes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Diolag can be shown if version code of your application changes(as I see from the code you've shared). So it is going to shown just once. If you want to show it anytime with a button click, then you may change the show method a little bit. See below:

```
    public void show(boolean showWithVersionCheck) {
        try {
            // Get the versionCode of the Package, which must be different (incremented) in each release on the market in the AndroidManifest.xml
            final PackageInfo packageInfo = mActivity.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(mActivity.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);

            final SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mActivity);

            final long lastVersionCode = prefs.getLong(LAST_VERSION_CODE_KEY, 0);

            boolean showDialog = true;
            if(showWithVersionCheck) {
                if(packageInfo.versionCode == lastVersionCode) {
                   showDialog = false; 
                }
            }

            if (showDialog) {
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "versionCode " + packageInfo.versionCode + "is different from the last known version " + lastVersionCode);

                final String title = mActivity.getString(R.string.app_name) + " v" + packageInfo.versionName;

                final String message = mActivity.getString(R.string.whatsnew);

                // Show the News since last version
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mActivity)
                        .setTitle(title)
                        .setMessage(message)
                        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new Dialog.OnClickListener() {

                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                // Mark this version as read
                                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                                editor.putLong(LAST_VERSION_CODE_KEY, packageInfo.versionCode);
                                editor.commit();
                                dialogInterface.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                builder.create().show();
            } else {
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "versionCode " + packageInfo.versionCode + "is already known");
            }

        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

And call it:

```
Button button = getYourButton();
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        new WhatsNewScreen(someActivityContext).show(false);
        // or show(true) if you want a version check 
        // If you are calling it from your MainActivity you can write MainActivity.this
        // instead of someActivityContext. 
    }
});
```

**Edit:** WhatsNewScreen does not extend from Activity, you can't start it with the code at the image you've shared.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your code. I got the feeling that it will work, but when I add it to the WhatsNewScreen Activity there are some errors, have a look on the Pic: http://i.stack.imgur.com/7GMt8.png

Comment: Thanks, now just one error left. :P look here: http://i.stack.imgur.com/eifNR.png

Comment: Thanks again! Hope not to make you go nuts, your code is error free now. But now I got an error in my MainActtivity where I call the WhatsNewScreen, see here: http://i.stack.imgur.com/qFmq3.png

Comment: fixed it by setting it to (true), thanks for your great help!